# Passing string rather than filename to -f option in jq under bash

Tags: bash, file, filter, jq

I'm curious whether I can replace *file name* with *a string* when using `-f` option of `jq`.

When I do

```
$ jq -nf <(echo \"hello world\")
```

it correctly outputs

```
"hello world"
```

But when I try

```
$ jq -nf <<<$'\"hello world\"'
```

this fails with error

```
jq: Could not open .: It's a directory
```

Anyone knows how to make this work? I know this is more of a `bash` question than `jq`.

`$ jq '.' <<< '"hello world"'` works though.

Thanks.

Comment: A herestring like that is the processes standard input, not a command line argument

Comment: @Philippe funny because `$ jq '.' <<< '"hello world"'` works without `/dev/stdin` part.

Comment: @Philippe yeh that is intended. from man page `jq [options...] filter [files...]`

Comment: @KamilCuk i want to substitute filename with <<<$'"hello world"'

Comment: @LoganLee You can't substitute a here-string for a filename; that's not how here-strings work. It's not at all like a filename, it's closer to a pipeline. That is, `jq '.' <<< '"hello world"'` is similar to `echo '"hello world"' | jq '.'` -- no argument is passed to the command, but the string is made available to it over standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/dev/stdin` to represent standard input as a file:

```
jq -nf /dev/stdin <<<$'\"hello world\"'
echo \"hello world\" | jq -nf /dev/stdin
```

Comment: do you know why `$ jq '.' <<< '"hello world"'` works though (without /dev/stdin)?

Comment: Weeelll, because the author of `jq` decided so (that when you do not give `-f` option, it reads from standard input by itself). I do not understand what is confusing - when writing a program, the author controls what happens when it happens. The logic could be just `if (is there -f option?) use_option_-f(); else use_/dev/stdin`

Comment: @LoganLee Using `-f` needs an explicit file to be specified

Comment: i guess `$ jq '.' <(echo '"hello world"')` is different from `$ jq '.' <<< '"hello world"'` although give the same output

Comment: `<(...)` creates a fifo and replaces `<(..)` by the name of the fifo. See `echo <(echo)`. `<<<` redirects the string to standard output.

Comment: this works as expected `$ cat 9<<<$'hello world' 0<&9` gives `hello world`.